# Javascript json data grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, grouping, distinct

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find a good example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Maybe I'm just not searching for the right thing. Please correct me if there's an explanation of this somewhere. Anyway...

I have JSON data structured like so...

```
{"Result":[
    {"Level":"ML","TeamName":"Team 1","League":"League 1"},
    {"Level":"ML","TeamName":"Team 2","League":"League 2"},
    {"Level":"ML","TeamName":"Team 3","League":"League 3"},
    {"Level":"3A","TeamName":"Team 4","League":"League 1"},
    {"Level":"3A","TeamName":"Team 5","League":"League 2"},
    {"Level":"3A","TeamName":"Team 6","League":"League 3"},
    {"Level":"2A","TeamName":"Team 7","League":"League 1"},
    {"Level":"2A","TeamName":"Team 8","League":"League 2"},
    {"Level":"2A","TeamName":"Team 9","League":"League 3"},
]}
```

I would like to group, or restructure it like so...

```
{"Result":[
    {"ML":[
        {"TeamName":"Team 1","League":"League 1"},
        {"TeamName":"Team 2","League":"League 2"},
        {"TeamName":"Team 3","League":"League 3"}
    ]},
    {"3A":[
        {"TeamName":"Team 4","League":"League 1"},
        {"TeamName":"Team 5","League":"League 2"},
        {"TeamName":"Team 6","League":"League 3"}
    ]},
    {"2A":[
        {"TeamName":"Team 7","League":"League 1"},
        {"TeamName":"Team 8","League":"League 2"},
        {"TeamName":"Team 9","League":"League 3"}
    ]}
]}
```

How would I accomplish this with Javascript/jQuery? Unfortunately I can't edit what the server is sending me.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) This is a trivial problem...

Comment: Convert the JSON to an object, copy relevant parts to another object, and convert 2nd object to json. You can do it.

Comment: @JonathanM That last step may not even be necessary, since assumedly they're going to want to actually do something with the object at some point.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried much. I'm trying to wrap my head around how to go about this. I don't know if I have to use a combination of loops and $.grep() for this or not. Any guidance or help would be great.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just keep track of it all in an object:

```
let groups = Object.create(null);

data.forEach(item => {
    if (!groups[item.Level]) {
        groups[item.Level] = [];
    }

    groups[item.Level].push({
        TeamName: item.TeamName,
        League: item.League
    });
});

let result =
    Object.entries(groups)
        .map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));
```

Comment: Can your for loop (and next line) be simplified into `for( item in data )` ?

Comment: @TimothyAaron: No, JavaScript's `for in` loop iterates over keys, not values, and you shouldn't use it to iterate over arrays. So, we're still waiting for widespread adoption of `for each` :D

Comment: He says he's using jQuery, so you could use $.each.

Comment: @Julian: Right, thanks; I'll add that.

Comment: That's great...thank you very much for some ideas.

Comment: I understood the first part of the jQuery code you gave, but then you lost me at `var result = $.map` is this just another way of doing it? If so, still dont follow that, but I presume I can just use the first part from `var groups`. It just seems like that second part has nothing to do with the first and is not needed. So im hoping its just an alternative

Comment: @Russell: The final result is an array (according to the question), and that’s the only way to get that array, but I accidentally passed `data` to `map` instead of `groups`.

Comment: Another way of iterating over objects I use a lot is this: 
`Object.keys(groups).forEach(function(key, index) {  //*code here* });`. I find it much cleaner than using call.